# Error in association tables in sequlelize with node

Tags: sequelize-cli

i am trying to join tables in node sequelize.try get datas from these two tables but its not working properly i think some problems in my code please help me to solve this problems
using linux mint.
 started node sequelize in few days.now using postgres database

```
emploee table
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = require("../config/database");
const dataType = db.sequelize;
const Employee = dataType.define("employee", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  employeename:{
    type:Sequelize.STRING
  },
});
module.exports = Employee;
```

user table

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize"); //use sequelize
 const db=require("../config/database"); //connect sequelize 
const dataType = db.sequelize;
const User = dataType.define("user",{  //table name
   id:{
       type:Sequelize.INTEGER,     //crete columns
       autoIncrement:true,
       primaryKey:true
   },
   username:{
        type:Sequelize.STRING
   },
   email:{
       type:Sequelize.STRING
   }

});
module.exports = User;    //export table
```

service.js

```
 exports.views= req =>{
    console.log("enterd get service",req.body);
    return User.findAll({
      include:[
        {
          model:Employee
        }
      ]
    }).then(User =>{
      console.log("user data is=",User);
      const resobj= User.map(user=>{
        return Object.assign(
          {},
          {
            email:User.email,
            sarath:user.sarath.map(Employee=>{
              return Object.assign(
                {},
                {


                  username:Employee.username,
                  employeename:Employee.employeename,
                }
              )
            })

          }
        )
      });
      return resobj;

    }).catch(err=>{
      return console.log("ERR IS",err);
    });

  };
```

sequelize

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
// const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const Op=Sequelize.Op;
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  "postgres", //db name
  "postgres", //username
  "postgres", //password

  {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "postgres",
    // operatorsAliases: false,
    opertorsAliases:{
       $or:Op.or
    },
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      require: 30000,
      idle: 1000
    },
    define: {
      freezeTableName: true
    }
  }
);
// define model/table
const models = {
  Employee: sequelize.define("../model/employee"),
  User:sequelize.define("../model/user")
};

//relations
models.Employee.hasMany(models.User);



models.Sequelize = Sequelize;
models.sequelize = sequelize;



module.exports = models;
```

this is my vs code output

```
enterd get service {}
ERR IS { SequelizeEagerLoadingError: employee is not associated to user!
    at Function._getIncludedAssociation (/home/sarath/Desktop/asset/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:711:13)
    at Function._validateIncludedElement (/home/sarath/Desktop/asset/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:615:53)
    at options.include.options.include.map.include (/home/sarath/Desktop/asset/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:511:37)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function._validateIncludedElements (/home/sarath/Desktop/asset/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:506:39)
    at Promise.try.then.then (/home/sarath/Desktop/asset/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1711:14)
    at tryCatcher (/home/sarath/Desktop/asset/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/sarath/Desktop/asset/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/sarath/Desktop/asset/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/sarath/Desktop/asset/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/sarath/Desktop/asset/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:694:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/home/sarath/Desktop/asset/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/home/sarath/Desktop/asset/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/sarath/Desktop/asset/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/sarath/Desktop/asset/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:632:19) name: 'SequelizeEagerLoadingError' }
GET /abc/users 200 20.215 ms - 57
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it might be easier for you if you declare your associations in your classes as per the documentation.. but you'll have to add some stuff to get it to work..

I don't really get why there would be a hasMany relationship between Employee and User, there is nothing in your models that would suggest that... Your models suggest that a User belongsTo Employee, and Employee hasOne User but because it is not by a foreign key id you will have to tell sequelize what keys to use to make the association...

Maybe something along the lines of

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Employee = sequelize.define('employee', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      employeename:{
        type:Sequelize.STRING
      },
    },
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'employee',
  });

  Employee.associate = function (models) {
    models.Employee.hasOne(models.User, { as: 'Employee', foreignKey: 'username', sourceKey: 'username' });    
  };

  return Employee;
};

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const User = sequelize.define('user', {
       id:{
           type:Sequelize.INTEGER,     //crete columns
           autoIncrement:true,
           primaryKey:true
       },
       username:{
            type:Sequelize.STRING
       },
       email:{
           type:Sequelize.STRING
       }
    },
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'user',
  });

  User.associate = function (models) {
    models.User.belongsTo(models.Employee, { as: 'User', foreignKey: 'username', sourceKey: 'username' });    
  };

  return User;
};
```

and then where you did this:  you need to add the part you were missing

```
// define model/table
const models = {
  Employee: sequelize.import('../model/employee'),
  User:sequelize.import('../model/user')
};

//You were missing this
Object.keys(models).forEach((modelName) => {
  if ('associate' in models[modelName]) {
    // console.log(models[modelName]);
    models[modelName].associate(models);
  }
});

models.Sequelize = Sequelize;
models.sequelize = sequelize;
```

I doubt you can copy and paste this and have it work without a few fixes as i just typed it in here and didn't check it in VSCode but this is the jist of it..

Comment: ERR IS { SequelizeEagerLoadingError: employee is not associated to user!
    at Function._getIncludedAssociation

Comment: Object.keys(models).forEach((Employee) => {
  if ('associate' in models[User]) {
    // console.log(models[modelName]);
    models[Employee].associate(this.User);
  }
});

Comment: });
User.associate = function (models) {
    models.User.belongsTo(models.Employee, { as: 'User', foreignKey: 'username', sourceKey: 'username' });    
  };

module.exports = User;    //export table

Comment: Employee.associate = function (models) {
  models.Employee.belongsTo(models.User, { as: 'Employee', foreignKey: 'username', sourceKey: 'username' });    
};
module.exports = Employee;

Comment: That is not gonna work, you'll have to revisit what i said and follow more closely... you have multiple belongsTo rather than the hasOne and belongsTo relationship i posted above... Also you should'nt post code in the comments... You should post it in it's entirety in an answer properly formatted, it makes it easier to help ya!  Just post another answer to the question  with the updates you made, or go back and edit your first question with the changes you made and i'll read it up there

Comment: Also your forEach does not look right yet, you have to pass all your models through that, as relationships have 2 sides

Comment: the hasOne part was my fault, i talked about it above the code i wrote but in my haste had them both written as belongsTo in the code, i corrected that